# Mobile app is not opening using java appium code for android devices

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

```
package appiumTestss.appiumTestss;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class CalculatorTest {

  static AppiumDriver driver;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hi kg12");
    openCalculator();

  }

  public static void openCalculator() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Moto");
    cap.setCapability("udid", "ZY223XXDVVAND");
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");

    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

    System.out.println("Application started....");
  }


}
```

Maven dependencies used are,

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId> 
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId> 
    <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Error observed:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:93)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:93) at
>   appiumTestss.appiumTestss.CalculatorTest.openCalculator(CalculatorTest.java:33)
>   at
>   appiumTestss.appiumTestss.CalculatorTest.main(CalculatorTest.java:16)

Comment: Maven dependencies used are,     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.3</version>
  </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.6</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Error observed, Hi kg12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
 at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:93)
 at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:93)
 at appiumTestss.appiumTestss.CalculatorTest.openCalculator(CalculatorTest.java:33)
 at appiumTestss.appiumTestss.CalculatorTest.main(CalculatorTest.java:16)

Answer (score 0):

Appium already have selenium inside, so no need to have separate selenium dependency. You need to add a capability **automationName** and the *AppiumDriver* without *MobileElement*. Sample code below:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Moto");
cap.setCapability("udid", "ZY223XXDVVAND");
cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```